# Check the database server name in a Postgres stored Procedure

Tags: postgresql

Is there any way to check the database server name in a Postgres stored Procedure?

I have a Stored Procedure to clear all dynamic data, to be used before Regression Testing an App that loads messages into the database.

I want to make sure it is only ever used in the DEV environment, not accidentally copied across to the Production Server and used on the LIVE database.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by saying "server name". Is it host name? DNS name? If you have  a test stage before deployment maybe you should add guards there to prevent utility functions from entering  production environment.

Comment: The stored procedure I refer to should never be copied to the LIVE DB, but I wanted to put in belts and braces just in case.  The DEV DB name currently includes the text "_dev_", so I am currently able to put a check in the stored procedure to abort if it is not the right DB.  Unfortunately, I am under pressure to rename the DEV DB to be the same as LIVE, but on a different environment/server.  So I was hoping to convert my check to test the DB server name that the database is hosted on.

Comment: You may use IP address (funkction inet_server_addr()), or you may use server parameters to signal DEV server environment (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/config-setting.html)

Comment: I was hoping to be able to test the server name, since that includes the text "dev".  If I use the IP address I have to keep a record of which address is the dev server, which is another thing that could go wrong.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by saying "server name". Is it host name? DNS name?